# Android: No CPU/ABI system image

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded Android Development kit, but while trying to create AVD, I am not able to install "ARM EABI" as I see only SDK Platform under "Android 4.4W" in the SDK Manager. I am not sure how to install ARM so that I can create an AVD.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Android 4.4W is for Android Wear devices, you will need to download another platform version in order to run standard apps

Comment: which one should i download and from where?

Comment: that depends on what API level you want to support, common ones will be either 4.4 Kitkat, or the new 5.0 Lollipop. You should be able to download them from the same place you downloaded the 4.4W SDK - the SDK manager